# Dynamically set div colors in sass/css from html(.erb)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm having trouble finding the best way to do this. I want to store the primary and secondary colors of objects in my database, then I want to display a divider using the two colors dynamically.

For instance...

[image]

*Notice the black parts of the two divs*

Most of the html/css solutions use css' `:before` & `:after` pseudo selectors to add the black part of the two divs. (Checkout code posted below). My initial thought is that I want to be able to pass the colors to the css/scss to set the before and after. After a little research, I realized that you can't do `:before/:after` via inline styles, which I would've said was an ugly solution anyway.

I'm more comfortable in React css in js, where this is a really simple task. I am also open to scrapping this html/css aspect and doing it differently since it seems overcomplicated with the way that I'm going about it.

Any help would be great! Thank you so much.

```
.tcd-primary {
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  float: left;

  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 100%;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid black; /* this should be the primary color instead of black */
  }
}

.tcd-secondary {
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  float: right;

  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: 100%;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid black; /* this should be the secondary color rather than black */
  }
}
```

Here's a simplified version of the html.erb:

```
<% teams.each do |team| %>
  <p><%= team.name %></p>

  <div class="tcd-primary" style="background: <%= team.primary_color %>;"></div>
  <div class="tcd-secondary" style="background: <%= team.secondary_color %>;"></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Correct! Just colored areas that I want to be to dynamically render for each team.

Comment: See the answer below. Use `color` as your inline style and then `currentColor` in the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these are just colored divs with no text we can take advantage of the inheritance of `currentColor`.

That is, if we define a **text** color, then the `currentColor` value can be used for the background and/or borders.

> The `currentColor` keyword represents the value of an element's color property. This lets you use the color value on properties that do not receive it by default.
>
> If `currentColor` is used as the value of the color property, it instead takes its value from the inherited value of the color property.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)</sup>

```css
.tcd-primary {
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  float: left;
  background: currentColor;
}

.tcd-primary:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 100%;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid currentColor;
}

.tcd-secondary {
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  float: right;
  background: currentColor;
}

.tcd-secondary:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 100%;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="tcd-primary" style="color: gold; "></div>
<div class="tcd-secondary" style="color:orange;"></div>

<div class="tcd-primary" style="color: green; "></div>
<div class="tcd-secondary" style="color:silver;"></div>
```

---

If you want to get *really* up to date you could use a single div with an angled linear gradient and [**CSS Custom Properties**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)

```css
div { 
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
  135deg,
  var(--color-1) 60%, 
  transparent 60%, transparent 62%, /* this is your gap */
  var(--color-2) 62%
  );
}
```

```html
<div style="--color-1: gold; --color-2: orange;"></div>
<div style="--color-1: green; --color-2: silver;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. Thanks for teaching me something new today.

Answer (score 0):

## Dynamic CSS Background Color

If you're using a framework like Vue and you are receiving your data from a database that contains stuff like the colors etc, you could either have specific classes but that gets tedious...

I recently found that you could pass a css variable to your html as a style property and then use that variable in your css...

*Of course, this needs to be edited to change the below red to a variable of your choosing, this is just the concept.*

```
<style>
    .myDiv {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background: var(--backgroundColor);
    }
</style>
<div class="myDiv" style="'--backgroundColor: red;'>Some block</div>
```

From here, you would use Javascript to either change the value of your css variable with the below

```
const root = document.querySelector(':root');
root.style.setProperty('--backgroundColor', 'blue');
```

Or in Vue logic simply dynamically change the value with something like this

```
<div class="myDiv" :style="'--backgroundColor: ' + backgroundVariable + ';'">
    Some Block
</div>
```